# Facebook HashKey Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm following the tutorial in Facebook and everything was fine. The sample apps were working fine, but today I'm getting:

```
Invalid key hash. The key hash HP... does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/app/NUMBEROFSAMPLEAPP (355198514515820)
```

I've already added the two keys I have: The first one using the java's keytool and the other using the code given at the Facebook tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started. The first one begins with DBxxxx and the second with HPxxxx.

Which one should I use? Do I have to add the "=" at the end of the key? Why it's not working if I have added the two keys?

Here's the code I added to get the key:

```
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.e("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For facebook SDK version 3.18:
Your keys needs to be 28 length. So answering your first question: you have to add "=" at the end if your key length is less than 28.
Trying to give you an answer for 2nd question (Why it's not working...). You need to update the sample app with the App ID given for Facebook when you created "Sample App" or whatever on [developers.facebook.com/apps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/). 
 Try to read all tutorial: [developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/#samples](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/#samples).
In other words you need to link any app with an app ID from Facebook.
If you need more help, just ask for it ;)

by the way, 3 good hints:

1. When you create an App on Facebook, it gives to you a better wizard for your new App on FB.
2. You don't have to follow those tutorials at all to see samples on action. Just create the App, select it from top left menu (Apps) on FB, press "Settings" below to Dashboard (on left panel) and add the hash keys created in tutorial. In your project (eclipse or Android Studio), change the string value of "app_id" on /res/values/strings.xml for the one available on "Settings" page.
3. By default you CAN NOT see friend's list :S ... you have to submit your app to Facebook if you want to see it.